# ng-required conflicts with ng-true-value and ng-false-value

Tags: javascript, angularjs, checkbox

if I set `ng-required="_something_"` inside a checkbox, `ng-true-value` and `ng-false-value` won't work.

See [plunker here](http://plnkr.co/edit/qBLIKaH1XmyQrSN5Xkz0?p=preview)

What I want to do is to send "1" if it is checked and "0" if it's not checked

Any hints?

thank you

Answer (score 1):

It seems to be the issue with Angular version 1.2.

Things break if multiple directives are placed on the same element.

Works under 1.5.

<kbd>**[Plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/yv6DjqLVYsVuhtrVzuDN?p=preview)**</kbd>

Comment: Thank you. Do they know or shall we open a bug report?

Comment: @alb.valente I am not sure if its an issue or intentional by design. Try reporting a bug anyway.